# Roblox - Making a custom event to detect mouse clicks?

Tags: lua, roblox

Firstly, I do not want to use the Mouse object, so MouseButton1Click is not an option. I want to use UserInputService, but my solution still seems unclean.

**ModuleScript:**

```
function GuiModule.Click(Input)
    if Input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 or Input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.Touch then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
```

**LocalScript:**

```
local GuiModule = require(game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.GuiModule)

Button.InputEnded:Connect(function(Input)
    if GuiModule.Click(Input) then --I really have to write an if statement for every InputEnded event?
        print("Button clicked")
    end
end)
```

Ideally, I want something like this, where **.Clicked** is a custom event that utilizes object-oriented programming in a module script. I've looked into metatables and metafunctions but I can't fully grasp their functionality to implement this, if its possible.

```
local GuiModule = require(game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.GuiModule)

Button.Clicked:Connect(function(Input)
    print("Button clicked")
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `Activated` [event](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/GuiButton/Activated) instead. It automatically handles different input types so you don't have to detect whether it's mouse or touch input.

```
Button.Activated:Connect(function()
    print("Button clicked or tapped")
end)
```